# I cannot start my camera, neither share my screen in Google Meet after upgrading Windows to Windows 11

Tags: camera, windows-11, google-meet

Since I've upgraded my Windows to Windows 11, I am not able to use the Google Meet.

My camera is OK in other programs, but the message "A câmera está iniciando" is persistent (my language is portuguese).

Moreover, when I try to share my screen, no things occur. I only can share Jamboards, but not my screen.

I have the last version of the Google Chrome, but also tried in Edge and cannot get success.

I've checked the permissions, it's all allowed.

Comment: Please add more details like the name and version of the web browser that you are using.

Comment: Also update the Camera Driver.  Windows catches many but not all, hardware driver updates.

Comment: @Rubén. I did it, thank you!

Comment: @Quiet_waters What do you mean by "I have the last version of Google Meet?"? If you are using Google Meet  in a web browser Google doesn't provide the version to the end-users because there isn't anything to be installed on the client-side. What are the steps that you follow to open Google Meet and start a videocall?

Comment: @Rubén I mean Chrome, I am sorry

Comment: Since the problem occurs with two different web browsers it's very likely that the problem is related to how the camera interacts with them. Include details about your camera (are you using a laptop with a built-in camera or it's a USB camera? and what you have tried to make sure that it is using the camera drivers updated. I haven't done anything yet go to the camera support page and check if there is a tool to download the appropriate version for your hardware architecture (32/64 bits) among additional instructions like running a troubleshooter, among other things.

Comment: @Rubén, I've finally get the right driver in https://support.lenovo.com/vn/en/downloads/ds551550-camera-driver-realtek-sonix-for-windows-11-64-bit-legion-7-16achg6. That worked. Thank you for assistance

Comment: Please consider to post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rubén and @John, I've finally get the right driver in https://support.lenovo.com/vn/en/downloads/ds551550-camera-driver-realtek-sonix-for-windows-11-64-bit-legion-7-16achg6. That worked. Thank you for the assistance.